# How to make a font-awesome spinner go around a circular picture

Tags: html, css, spinner, font-awesome

I have a circular image placed in a `div` tag. Now I want to place a font-awesome spinner over this image.

The effect I'm looking for is to make spinning image border, for example with [this spinner icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/circle-o-notch/).

The spinner and image must have the same radius.

The solution can be made without a font-awesome spinner, but with pure CSS3.

Comment: Can you post your code so far? or fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font Awesome can do the work for you, but if you wish to make any HTML element rotate endlessly, you can use the [`@keyframes` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)—supplemented by `@-webkit-keyframes` for Safari support—to define the rotating behavior. Use the [`animation` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) to apply this behavior to an HTML element.

The snippet below defines the `rotating` animation and applies it to `.circle`. The `.circle` element and the image are placed with `position: absolute` so that the circle goes around the image.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.circle {
  animation: rotating 2.5s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}

#demo {
  padding: 40px;
  color: #222;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 130px;
}

#demo img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="demo">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_Fe2cRDzAEE4mE5DDxYsbx9Emt2aQYVs-kmsDnOc8PeHOSlYV" />
  <div class="circle fa fa-circle-o-notch"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chrome is now using the un-prefixed property

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-circle-o-notch"><img href="your-image" id="image"></img></i>
```

And add this to your css:

```
#image {
    display: inline;
}
```

Look at the [examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)
And display [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).